# copy div data that contains grid view

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I m implementing copy to clipboard functionality for div that contains asp.net gridview.
my code is working on i.e only now how can i make it for all browsers

```
function CopyGridView() {

       var div = document.getElementById('div1');                  
       div.contentEditable = true;
       var controlRange;
       if (document.body.createControlRange) {
           controlRange = document.body.createControlRange();
           controlRange.addElement(div);
           controlRange.execCommand('Copy');
       }
                  div.contentEditable = 'false';
}
```

Please help.

Regards,
-Nitin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dataToCopy = 'Hi';
window.clipboardData.setData('text',dataToCopy);
```

http://help.dottoro.com/ljctuhrg.php

Answer (score 0):

```
window.clipboardData.setData('text',text);
```

Comment: can u pls tell me what to pass in parameters.. i m just newbie in this.